# AutoHotKey: Merge scripts that monitor selection in Firefox and other programs

Tags: autohotkey

I am struggling with a script that monitors selections by mouse in FireFox, Adobe Acrobat and one more program and then copies this selection to clipboard and changes it according to a regex. For each program another regex is needed. Each script works as a separate program, but when I merge them, the copied text is not changed according to my regex.

Script for Adobe Acrobat:

```
#ifWinActive ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow
~LButton::
now := A_TickCount
while GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
    continue
if (A_TickCount-now > 600 )
{   
    Send ^c
    copied := true
}
return

OnClipboardChange:
if !copied
    return

copied := false
ToolTip % Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\r\n", " ")
SetTimer, ToolTipOff, -1000
return

ToolTipOff:
ToolTip
return
```

And stript for Firefox:

```
#ifWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
~LButton::
now := A_TickCount
while GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
    continue
if (A_TickCount-now > 600 )
{   
    Send ^c
    copied := true
}
return

OnClipboardChange2:
if !copied
    return

copied := false
ToolTip % Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "[0-9]\.\s*|\s?\([^)]*\)|\.")
SetTimer, ToolTipOff1, -1000
return

ToolTipOff1:
ToolTip
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#If` does only work on hotkeys, not on labels. Using OnClipboardChange seems unnecessary. When you press ctrl+c you already know that the clipboard changed.
I also really recommend setting indentations for hotkeys and also #If statements.
Here is how I would do it:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow") || WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")
    ~LButton::
        now := A_TickCount
        while GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
            continue
        if (A_TickCount-now > 600 )
        {   
            Send ^c
            if WinActive("ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow")
            {
                regex := "\r\n"
                replace := " "
            }
            else if WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")
            {
                regex := "[0-9]\.\s*|\s?\([^)]*\)|\."
                replace := ""
            }
            ToolTip % Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, regex, replace)
            SetTimer, ToolTipOff, -1000
        }
    return
#If

ToolTipOff:
    ToolTip
return
```

(untested)

edit:

```
.....
    ~Left::
    ~Right::
    ~Up::
    ~Down::
        now := A_TickCount
        while GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
            continue
        if (A_TickCount-now > 600 )
        {   
            oldShiftState := GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
            Send, {Shift Up}
            Send ^c
            If (oldShiftState)
                Send, {Shift Down}
            .....
```

(untested)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Any chance of working also for selecting by keyboard (shift + arrows to select text)? Selecting by mouse sometimes fails to work in Acrobat.

Comment: Well there are multiple ways you could achieve that. I added some code to my answer. That would be one way of doing it.

Comment: This time neither selection by mouse or keyboard works.